# Service Routing in Kubernete using Istio based on JWT token

Tags: istio

I would like to use istio in my kubernetes cluster for routing. My use case is I have 3 service running in my cluster - A, B, and C. I would like to route my traffic to these services based on some value in JWT token. Is it doable using istio ?

Comment: It seems it was requested here as well repository is archived. https://github.com/istio/old_mixer_repo/issues/495. Is it available now ?

Answer (score 2):

I found the following Github issues [#3763](https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/issues/3763), [#8444](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/8444) might be relevant to your initial request, and based on the contributors comments, the feature of routing network traffic with [JWT](https://jwt.io/) claims is not expected in further Istio [Mixer](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/#mixer) adapter development.

However, I assume that you can configure Envoy [HTTP filters](http://ttps://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/jwt_authn_filter#jwt-authentication) in order to fetch JWT token from HTTP header and use match option for [RequirementRule](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v2/config/filter/http/jwt_authn/v2alpha/config.proto#envoy-api-msg-config-filter-http-jwt-authn-v2alpha-requirementrule) and apply some [Lua](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http_filters/lua_filter#lua) script that will afford routing functionality. The other way would be using intermediate proxy server like [NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/blog/authentication-content-based-routing-jwts-nginx-plus/) which has content-based routing with JWTs out the box within [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/kubernetes-ingress-controller) for Kubernetes.